# How to change object structure into array structure for highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, highcharts

I want to change this object structure

```
     [
        {
            "tahun": "2010",
            "apel": 100,
            "pisang": 200,
            "anggur": 300,
            "nanas": 400,
            "melon": 500
        },
        {
            "tahun": "2011",
            "apel": 145,
            "pisang": 167,
            "anggur": 210,
            "nanas": 110,
            "melon": 78
        }
     [
```

into this array structure for my highchart in Django,

```
[
 ["2010",100],
 ["2010",200],
 ["2010",300],
 ["2010",400],
 ["2010",500],
 ["2011",145],
 ["2011",167],
 ["2011",210],
 ["2011",110],
 ["2011",78]
]
```

Or if you have any method like using AJAX it will be very helpful

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: what do u mean?? theres the code...

Comment: It would be nice, if you'd tried something, and also if you'd know [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert your list of dictionaries to a list of lists on the server side you can do it like so:

```
>>> data = [{'tahun': '2010', 'apel': 100, 'pisang': 200, 'anggur': 300, 'nanas': 400, 'melon': 500}, {'tahun': '2011', 'apel': 145, 'pisang': 167, 'anggur': 210, 'nanas': 110, 'melon': 78}]
>>> [[x['tahun'], x['apel']] for x in data]
[['2010', 100], ['2011', 145]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the original structure into the structure you need with this:

```
const data = [
  {
      "tahun": "2010",
      "apel": 100,
      "pisang": 200,
      "anggur": 300,
      "nanas": 400,
      "melon": 500
  },
  {
      "tahun": "2011",
      "apel": 145,
      "pisang": 167,
      "anggur": 210,
      "nanas": 110,
      "melon": 78
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const year = curr.tahun;
  delete curr.tahun;
  return [...prev, ...Object.keys(curr).map(key => [year, curr[key]])];
}, []);
```

Not the prettiest but hey, it works.